# How to catch a bash error when the script is run through python

Tags: python, bash, sh

I am trying to run a `bash` (or `sh`) script through a python script like so:

```
import os
cmd="/bin/echo {1..200000}"
out=os.system(cmd)
```

However, the command does not run and I get the following error:

```
/bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

I want to be able to capture this error specifically in my python script. `try/except` does not work here as it is not a python error, hence I want to know if there is any other way to capture this.

Comment: dont use os.system, use the subprocess module which has classes capable of reading stderr

Comment: Are you interested in "Argument list too long" specifically, or generally when the command does not execute successfully?

Comment: @thatotherguy I am specifically looking at "Argument list too long" error

Comment: One Alternative solution can be `eval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the error isn't happening in Python.  The error happens in bash which is running as a separate process at that point.  Take a look at the Python module "subprocess".  It is more complex to set up than os.system(), but it allows you to capture stdin and stdout and process them after the process has terminated.

Comment: The extra benefit of this is that you can skip bash/sh entirely, invoke the same command yourself (`subprocess.run(["/bin/echo"] + list(map(str, range(1, 200001))))`), and then it'll raise an OSError that can not only be caught, but can be differentiated from all other execution failures with its `errno` property